# In C#, parse out biweekly sets of dates from a collection of dates?

Tags: c#, datetime, collections, recurrence

I [recently asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15170391/parse-out-monthly-items-from-a-collection-of-datetime-objects), to take a list of datetime objects and parse out:

1. *Weekly Recurrence:* Collections of dates that match the same dayOfWeek, hour, minute to get a set of lists where each item in the list matches that Key where:

   Key is concatenation of DayOfWeek + hour + minute
2. *Monthly Recurrence:* Collections of dates that match the same weekOfMonth, dayOfWeek, hour, minute to get a set of lists where each item in the list matches that Key where:

   Key is concatenation of WeekOfMonth + DayOfWeek + hour + minute

both of these are working great.

I have an additional requirement now that I am struggling with to support bi weekly recurrence (every other week).  I am trying to figure out the right key to match on that would work as both the other use cases above have logical computed key but can't figure the algorith / key for every other week

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to figure out the week number for the date in question.

For example:

```
var dt = new DateTime(...); // your datetime
var cal = new System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar();
var weekNum = cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

There are different strategies for counting weeks of the year, which you specify with a `CalendarWeekRule` and corresponding `DayOfWeek` for the starting day of the week.  You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx).

Once you have a week number, you can do some math to make it "bi-weekly":

```
int biweeklyKey = weekNum % 2;
```

The value will be either 0 or 1, which you can use as a key in your algorithm.